# Collapsible network plot in R

Tags: r, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I am trying to implement collapsible network in R based on the blog post [more network layouts](http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2015/1/23/week-03-more-network-layouts). However, I am always getting the error of `Object not found`.

```
devtools::install_github
devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/networkD3@feature/d3.chart.layout")
library(htmltools)
library(networkD3)

hc = hclust(dist(mtcars))

treeNetwork( 
   as.treeNetwork(hc, "mtcars")
)

tagList(
  lapply(
    c("tree.cartesian"
      ,"tree.radial"
      ,"cluster.cartesian"
      ,"cluster.radial"
     )
    ,function(chartType){
      hierNetwork(as.treeNetwork(hc), type=chartType, zoomable=T,    collapsible=T)
    }
  )
)
tree.cartesian
```

EDIT 1

How can we use these graphs for an edges file to build a network? Example:

```
From   To
 A      B
 A      C
 A      D
 D      L
 L      J
 J      T
 B      O
```

Comment: Where are you getting "Object not found"?

Comment: @Marcelo - In the console itself

Comment: I meant to ask after which line on the code you are getting the error.

Comment: @Marcelo - After tree.cartesain

Comment: Can you try this command: `hierNetwork( as.treeNetwork(hc), type = "tree.cartesian", zoomable = T, collapsible = T )`
It should open the browser with the network chart.

Comment: @Marcelo- Thanks a lot..Its coming up just fine...

Comment: - The code should show all the types of charts but it is not working for me also. You can manually see the other types by replacing `type = "tree.cartesian"` with the other types:   "tree.radial", "cluster.cartesian"  and "cluster.radial"

Comment: Yes..that should solve the issue...One more thing...is it possible to use this for a data frame which is essentially an edges file. example in the edit of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The current official dev version of networkD3 (v0.4.9000 as of 2017.09.02) has a new function `treeNetwork` that enables collapsible trees.

```
devtools::install_github("christophergandrud/networkD3")
library(networkD3)

hc <- hclust(dist(mtcars))
treeNetwork(hc)

edges <- read.table(header = T, text = "
From   To
NA     A
A      B
A      C
A      D
D      L
L      J
J      T
B      O
")

edges <- as_treenetdf(edges, cols = c(nodeId = "To", parentId = "From"))
treeNetwork(edges)
```

It's still in development, so we'd appreciate [feedback](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues).

Comment: Thank you, how can we plot a vertical tree? Any plans for a new CRAN release?

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
library(networkD3)
to <- c("a","a","a","d","l","j","b") 
from <- c("b","c","d","l","j","t","o")
df <-data.frame(to,from)
simpleNetwork(df)
```

You should use the official networkD3 package:

```
install.packages("networkD3")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the `tree.cartesian` object is supposed to be in your code, but you're getting the error "Object not found" because the `tree.cartesian` object is never being created in your code.

Having said that, your code will work if you remove your `lapply` command from the `tagList` function. Or more succinctly...

```
devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/networkD3@feature/d3.chart.layout")
library(networkD3)

hc = hclust(dist(mtcars))

hierNetwork(as.treeNetwork(hc), type = 'tree.cartesian', zoomable = T, collapsible = T)
# or
hierNetwork(as.treeNetwork(hc), type = 'tree.radial', zoomable = T, collapsible = T)
# or
hierNetwork(as.treeNetwork(hc), type = 'cluster.cartesian', zoomable = T, collapsible = T)
# or
hierNetwork(as.treeNetwork(hc), type = 'cluster.radial', zoomable = T, collapsible = T)
```

Just to be clear, you are using a branch of networkD3, which (as far as I know) is no longer being developed. There is some current intention to add this feature to the official networkD3 branch, but at the moment (v0.3.1), this feature (collapsible branches) is not currently available.

Comment: does this answer your question?