# R/Javascript: Collapsing and Expanding Networks

Tags: javascript, r, graph, igraph

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following graph network data:

```
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)

from <- c("Boss", "TeamA", "TeamA", "TeamA", "SubteamA1", "SubteamA1", "SubteamA1", "SubteamA2", "SubteamA2", "SubteamA2", "SubteamA3", "SubteamA3", "SubteamA3")
to <- c("TeamA", "SubteamA1", "SubteamA2", "SubteamA3", "employee1", "employee2", "employee3", "employee4", "employee5", "employee6", "employee7", "employee8", "employee9")
a1 = data_frame <- data.frame(from, to)


from <- c("Boss", "TeamB", "TeamB", "TeamB", "SubteamB1", "SubteamB1", "SubteamB1", "SubteamB2", "SubteamB2", "SubteamB2", "SubteamB3", "SubteamB3", "SubteamB3")
to <- c("TeamB", "SubteamB1", "SubteamB2", "SubteamB3", "employee10", "employee11", "employee12", "employee13", "employee14", "employee15", "employee16", "employee17", "employee18")
a2 = data_frame <- data.frame(from, to)


final = rbind(a1, a2)
```

I then made it into a graph network and visualized it:

```
# Convert the data frame to an igraph object
g <- graph_from_data_frame(final, directed=FALSE)

# Plot the graph
plot(g)

# Optional visualization
visIgraph(g)

visIgraph(g) %>%
  visHierarchicalLayout(direction = "LR") %>%
  visInteraction(navigation = "zoom") %>%
  visInteraction(navigation = "drag") %>%
  visOptions(selectedBy = "to", 
             highlightNearest = TRUE, 
             nodesIdSelection = TRUE)
```

[image]

**My Question:** I have been trying to find if there some way such that when you run the graph, it only shows one node on the screen (boss node) - and when you click on the boss node, it expands into 3 nodes (boss, team a, team b), and if you click on "team a", it expands into sub teams ... but if you double click, it collapse back to the previous layer.

The closest thing I could find to this is here: https://github.com/datastorm-open/visNetwork/issues/307

But is there some easier way to do this in R/javascript? In the end, the final output should be a (standalone) HTML file that can be viewed offline.

Thanks!

Note:

- I am NOT interested in a shiny web app.
- I would be looking for something like this: [D3.js Titles on Collapsible Force-Directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747638/d3-js-titles-on-collapsible-force-directed-graph) , [How can I collapse (show and hide) the child nodes of a parent node in d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175630/how-can-i-collapse-show-and-hide-the-child-nodes-of-a-parent-node-in-d3-js), [Programmatic access of data in d3.js v6 collapsible tree via selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67596316/programmatic-access-of-data-in-d3-js-v6-collapsible-tree-via-selectors), [R collapsibleTree: add images dynamically in tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828655/r-collapsibletree-add-images-dynamically-in-tooltip)
- This would be really interesting if it had a search bar and a "zoom out" option: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/collapsibleTree/html/collapsibleTreeNetwork.html , https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/collapsibleTree/readme/README.html, https://adeelk93.github.io/collapsibleTree/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option could be using `visOptions` with the `collapse` argument:

> : Custom option. Just a Boolean, or a named list. Collapse /
> Uncollapse nodes using double-click. In dev.

So this makes it possible to collapse when double-clicking on a node. You could change the shape to give it a different shape when it is collapsed. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
library(igraph)
library(visNetwork)

visIgraph(g) %>%
  visInteraction(navigation = "zoom") %>%
  visInteraction(navigation = "drag") %>%
  visOptions(collapse = list(enabled = TRUE, keepCoord = TRUE, clusterOptions = list(shape = "circle")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

When clicking on your boss node:

[image]

Or for example on TeamA:

[image]

---

> 1. Is it possible to remove the "cluster" label on each node?

You could add `label = FALSE` like this:

```
visIgraph(g) %>%
  visInteraction(navigation = "zoom") %>%
  visInteraction(navigation = "drag") %>%
  visOptions(collapse = list(enabled = TRUE, keepCoord = TRUE, clusterOptions = list(shape = "circle", label = FALSE)))
```

Example on TeamB:

[image]

Comment: @ Quinten: Thank you so much for your answer! I added "%>% visPhysics (enabled = FALSE)" to the code and the network graph stops "wiggling"

Comment: Some questions I had:

Comment: 1) Is it possible to remove the "cluster" label on each node?

Comment: 2) When you collapse a node, is it possible to make the node size (i.e. radius) proportional to the number of mini-nodes that get swallowed?

Comment: Hi @stats_noob, I added some code for your first question. I am not sure how to achieve your second question. Sorry.

Comment: @ Quinten; I have accepted your answer Thank you again!

Comment: I am working on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75348270/r-modifying-an-r-markdown-tutorial ... can you please take a look at it later if you have time?

Answer (score 1):

You might try

- install the chart layout feature from github:

```
devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/networkD3@feature/d3.chart.layout")
```

which makes some layouts of {[networkD3](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3)} collapsible (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42640899/20513099)).
Example:

```
## devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/networkD3@feature/d3.chart.layout")
library(networkD3)

hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")

hierNetwork(as.treeNetwork(hc), 
            type = 'cluster.cartesian', 
            zoomable = TRUE,
            collapsible = TRUE
            )
```

- using {r2d3} to [provide a custom d3 script](https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3/reference/r2d3.html) which could be [the one for collapsible force networks](https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph/blob/master/example/expandable-nodes/index.html) your datastorm example is probably based on.